# Not able to set background for the fixed Div

Tags: css

I have a issue with my CSS, as i am not able to set a background image to a fixed div. below is the link to codepen where i have contructed my html page. i really dono how i can set background image in code pen that is why i have set background color. I have a div with id right-bar which is postion fixed, and i have set a background image for it, but it doesn't display any background. if i remove the position fixed then background appears, but problem is i want to have a scroll flexibility which i get when the div is fixed.

**CodePen**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lmbtd

**HTML**

```
    <body>
    <div style="width=100%;height=100%;">
        <div id="form" style="width: 40%; float:left; height=100%;">
            <div id="left-bar">
                <input type="text" id="ititle" name="title" placeholder="Title Goes Here">
                <br>
                <textarea id="tContent" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                <br>
                <input class="button black" id="submitBtn" type="button" value="Add Me to the Note" onclick="fnSaveContent(event)">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="notes" style="width: 60%; float:right;">
            <div class="NoteBar">
                <p>Notes</p>
            </div>
            <div id="right-bar" style="
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(../images/bg-right-column.jpg);
    /* background-repeat: repeat; */
"><div class="noteContent scdf " id="idc7" style="
    background: url(../images/bg-right-column.jpg);
"> <h3>scdf</h3> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div><div class="noteContent wd " id="idc6"> <h3>wd</h3> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div><div class="noteContent qweqweqwe " id="idc5" style="
    background: url(../images/bg-right-column.jpg);
"> <h3>qweqweqwe</h3> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div><div class="noteContent re " id="idc4"> <h3>RE</h3> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div><div class="noteContent sadsdasd " id="idc3"> <h3>sadsdasd</h3> <p>asdasdasd</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div><div class="noteContent asdasd " id="idc2"> <h3>asdasd</h3> <p>asdas</p> <div class="absButton"><span class="x-btn edit" onclick="fnEdit(this,event)">Edit</span> <span class="x-btn delete" onclick="fnDelete(this,event)">Remove</span></div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}

/* ------------------------------------------------
  CSS Reset Code Starts
  -----------------------------------------------*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

#left-bar{
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

#right-bar{
    margin: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    background: url(../images/bg-right-column.jpg);
}
body{
    background: url(../images/skulls.png) repeat;
}

input,textarea {
    border: 5px solid white; 
    width: 375px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    -moz-box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    box-shadow: 
      inset 0 0 8px  rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
            0 0 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); 
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#submitBtn {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #1b9edb) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #1b9edb 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#1b9edb');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:50px;
    line-height:15px;
    width : 416px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
}
#submitBtn:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #1b9edb), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #1b9edb 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1b9edb', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#1b9edb;
}

#submitBtn:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.NoteBar{
    height : 50px;
    background: rgba(77,77,77,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(77,77,77,1)), color-stop(12%, rgba(89,89,89,1)), color-stop(25%, rgba(102,102,102,1)), color-stop(39%, rgba(71,71,71,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(18,18,18,1)), color-stop(76%, rgba(43,43,43,1)), color-stop(91%, rgba(28,28,28,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(18,18,18,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(77,77,77,1) 0%, rgba(89,89,89,1) 12%, rgba(102,102,102,1) 25%, rgba(71,71,71,1) 39%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 51%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 60%, rgba(43,43,43,1) 76%, rgba(28,28,28,1) 91%, rgba(18,18,18,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4d4d4d', endColorstr='#121212', GradientType=1 );
}



.NoteBar p{
    font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
    Color : white;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.noteContent{
    border-bottom: 1px grey solid;
    border-left: 1px rgb(138, 125, 125) solid;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.noteContent h3{
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
}

.noteContent p{
    padding-left: 10px;

}

.noteContent .absButton{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}

#notes{
    background: url(../images/bg-right-column.jpg);
    color:white;
}

/*Edit Icon
span.edit {
    height: 10px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
}

span.edit:after {
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    width: 6px;
    background: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0px;
}

span.edit:before {
    content: '';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-width: 5px 3px 0 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #333 transparent transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
}

span.delete {
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #333;
    margin: 15px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

span.delete:after {
    content: '';
    width: 25px;
    height: 4px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 12px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}*/

.x-btn{
    border: none;
    color: gold;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It seems to work just fine (safari), but you have it defined in both your css and inline in the element.  Are you changing it on the element or in css? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqpjG)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the image you have used for background is not available. I have added some sample images from online and apply the same. The background is applying as usual. Check the below fiddle link.

```
<div id="right-bar" style="
max-height: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
position: fixed;
background: url(http://isc.stuorg.iastate.edu/wp-content/uploads/sample.jpg);">
```

[**Udpated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvHzg)